# SQL Query Question

Tags: t-sql

I am using the following query to list these records between specified dates.But ,it's not working.Also,don't gives me error.Just is coming blank screen.it's has column name.
Any problem the following query?

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
select *from tamirarizakaydi where tarih between '31.01.2011 ' and ' 04.02.2011'
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a superfluous space at the beginning of `' 04.02.2011'` and at the end of `'31.01.2011 '` no idea if that affects anything. What is the datatype of the `tarih` column? Also use ISO format `yyyymmdd`.

Answer (score 2):

The leading and trailing spaces don't make any difference as far as I can see.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy 
select CAST('31.01.2011 ' as date) , CAST(' 04.02.2011' as date), CAST('31.01.2011 ' as datetime), CAST(' 04.02.2011' as datetime)
```

Returns

```
---------- ---------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2011-01-31 2011-02-04 2011-01-31 00:00:00.000 2011-02-04 00:00:00.000
```

I'm going to guess that `tarih` is stored as a string or you don't have any matching rows.

If `tarih` is a character based column then your query will be doing a lexicographic comparison and look for rows where `tarih >= '31.01.2011 ' and 'tarih <= ' 04.02.2011'` No rows can match this condition as the end of the range is alphabetically before the start of the range.